# "The type or namespace name 'XXXX' not found" but already referenced

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003

My project `A` reference a project `B` to get database access. The `B`'s DLL is in my `References` folder under `A`, and I have all the necessary `using` in every file and class.

I attached the `aspnet_wp.exe` process under `A` to do some debug, but I didn't get what I want; so I made some changes to `B` and compiled it (which was successful), then I compiled `A`...

When `The type or namespace name 'XXXX' not found` (not exactly, the message I got it in french: `Le type ou le nom d'espace de noms 'XXXX' est introuvable`) was thrown in every file I put `using B`.

Already to remove and read the reference to `B`, same problem...

Can you help me to find what I did wrong? this is driving me crazy.

BTW, I'm using VS2003 and .Net 1.1. So lame, I know.

Comment: How did you add the reference? Did you add a project reference or did you reference the compiled dll using the browse tab?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What weird... I found the solution. The A project didn't want to copy the last version of the B's dll inside it's own \bin... so I deleted every file in this folder, recompiled A.. and it's working. F****ng VS 2003 which can't handle files correctly.

Sorry for the inconvenience, may my question help someone :)

Comment: if you have found a solution by yourself, feel free to accept your own answer.